# How to check if class attribute exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if there is no class tag within a `<li> </li>` tag.

For example, if I have this:

```
<li class="menu...."> words </li>
```

I want to ignore it. However if I have this:

```
<li> words </li>
```

I want to use it.

What I currently have is something along the lines of:

```
$("li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).classList.contains('') {
        do function
    }
})
```

However, this is not working - how would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're missing a paren. if(!this.className){ ... }

Comment: Did you mean to check if there is no class attribute ?

Comment: @Arkni Yes, I'm checking if there is no class attribute

Comment: @SurferL, then the answer of **Sterling Archer** wil help you, see below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('li:not([class])');
```

This will select all `li` elements without a class at all. You can replace `[class]` with a specific class as well, or use `hasClass`.

Comment: would that hit empty class attribs ?

Comment: @dandavis no, OP wants `li` without the class attribute, so an empty class will not be selected

Comment: @SterlingArcher Would you then do the function after that like: `$('li:not([class])'); do function` ?

Comment: Running it through the each loop will be the same as what you did in your question

Comment: @SterlingArcher So it would be:  `$('li:not([class])').each(function() { etc }` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
$("li:not(.menu)").whatever();
```

That's not the fastest way necessarily; it may be faster to do this:

```
$("li").filter(function() { return !$(this).hasClass("menu"); }).whatever()
```

*edit* if you want to operate on `<li>` elements that have *no* class, then just check the `.className` property:

```
$("li").filter(function() { return !$(this).prop("className"); }).whatever()
```

However, I would suggest that that's not a good coding pattern. It's fragile because it relies on any future changes to your page for purposes completely unrelated to what you're doing now *not* involving the addition of a class. You'd be better off explicitly checking for specific classes that you're not interested in.

Like, maybe 3 months from now, somebody decides that all the list items that are about penguins be made black and white. You then add the class "penguin" to all those `<li>` elements. If you don't remember this change you're making now, all of a sudden that functionality will be broken.

Comment: OP is trying to check for the class attribute from what I understand

Comment: @Huangism he wants to operate on `<li>` elements that do *not* have a particular class.

Comment: It's just an example, see the first line in the description. By tag I am sure OP means attribute

Comment: @Huangism yes I see. I explained in my update that that's probably an anti-pattern to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("li").each(function() {

    if (!$(this).prop("class")) {

        doFunction();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/nuyesezacogo/1/edit)

Comment: if you want to use prop(), use "className" because "class" is a legacy binding to the attribute. search http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js for "propFix:"...

Comment: @dandavis - What I understand is that (only) for < IE 8? Right?

Answer (score 0):

The `classList` is only available on `Element` instances, not on the jQuery object.

```
$("li").each(function() {
  if (this.classList.length === 0) {
    do function
  }
})
```